# C++: Clear bits of a single precision float

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm currently converting a program that was originally intended for OpenCL to C++ and I'm having a bit of trouble with one particular part of it.

One of the expressions commonly used in said program involves taking a 32 bit float, converting it to an integer (i.e. not actually rounding it to an int, but interpreting the same data as an int - think reinterpret_cast), performing some bit twiddling magic on it and then converting it back to a float (once again, not actual conversion, but reinterpretation of the same data). While this works well in OpenCL, with C++ and gcc this violates strict aliasing rules, breaking the program if optimization is enabled and, depending on the architecture, may involve an expensive load-hit-store since float and integer registers are separated.

I've been able to avoid most of these expressions efficiently, but there is one I'm not sure about whether it could be done faster. Basically, the intention is to clear a number of bits from the right of a float; the OpenCL code does this similar to this:

```
float ClearFloatBits(float Value, int NumberOfBits) {
    return __int_as_float((__float_as_int(Value) >> NumberOfBits) << NumberOfBits);
}
```

Since this is essentially rounding down from a specified (binary) digit, my C++ version now looks like this:

```
float ClearFloatBits(float Value, int NumberOfBits) {
    float Factor = pow(2.0f, 23 - NumberOfBits);

    return ((int)(Value*Factor))/Factor;
}
```

Where the `pow` and the division are of course replaced by a LUT lookup and a respective multiplication, here omitted for better readability.

Is there a better way to do this? What bugs me in particular is the (int) conversion to round down, which I guess is the most expensive part. It is guaranteed that the float passed to the function is a number between 1.0 (inclusive) and 2.0 (exclusive), if that helps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand correcltly, what you're actually doing is truncating the float... Why just not use floor()?

Comment: Yep is there any reason why you're not just using the normal math functions? These work fine on floats after all.

Comment: Ah, this reminds me of that congenial fast inverse sqrt hack. (Hmm, Noobody might actually mean that very trick.) It is so amazingly cunning that I had it on my whiteboard for motivation :)

Comment: Floor is obscenely expensive computational wise. Replacing it by (int) led to a decrease of total execution time by more than 15% for the whole program, of which this function is only a tiny part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the union hack instead:

```
float ClearFloatBits(float Value, int NumberOfBits) {
   union { unsigned int int_val; float flt_val; } union_hack;
   union_hack.flt_val = Value;
   (union_hack.int_val >>= NumberOfBits) <<= NumberOfBits;
   return union_hack.flt_val;
}
```

Strictly speaking, this is undefined behavior. Per both the C and C++ standards, <strike>it is illegal to write</strike> the result of writing to one member of a union and then reading from another member without first writing to that other member is undefined.

However, this usage of unions is so widespread and so ancient that no compiler writer that I know of obeys the standard. In practice, the behavior is very well defined and is exactly what you would expect. That said, this hack might not work if ported to some very strange architecture machine that uses a very strictly conforming compiler.

Comment: This still violates strict aliasing rules

Comment: It does not violate the strict alias rule, which pertains to pointers only. Without strict aliasing, the compiler would have to be very conservative about how it treats any pointer. The union hack does violate other rules. C standard, 6.5.16.1 para 3: "If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." C++ has a similar rule.

Comment: That said, the result of invoking this supposed undefined behavior is well defined on every compiler, every machine I have worked on. Moreover, that well-defined behavior does exactly what one wants. The ability to reliably assign to one member of a union and then read from another is a nearly-universal extension to the language.

Comment: This not only works perfectly, I've also seen a great increase in performance! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Those compiler obey the standard too, UB doesn't automatically mean to do something bad, they can do something good and deterministic too.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: If they weren't standard in this respect, David wouldn't have described it as an _extension_. Compiler extensions are pretty much by definition cases in which the implementation defines behavior that the standard doesn't impose.

Comment: I have to ask, why use two shifts instead of a bit-and operation?

Comment: @MSalters: where in the standard does it say that UB with unions may not behave the way it does in current compilers (only then one could say the compiler does not obey the standard, since if the standard would say "do whatever you want", then the compiler would obey the standard with whatever it wants)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I quoted line verse from the C99 standard in my first comment to this answer. The wording in the C++ standard (5.17 para 8) is identical. Strictly speaking, this is UB in both C and in C++. Practically speaking, it works because it is a nearly-universal extension.

Comment: @Mark B: I see two possible implementations that use a bitwise and: Make a `const static` array of the bitmasks, or build the bitmask on the fly. The former will involve accessing an array element in stored memory, and that will almost certainly be much slower than will diddling the bits in a register. The latter will still involve shift operations, so once again no joy. I would hazard that any implementation that uses a bitwise and would be slower than using two shifts.

Comment: @MarkB: The `&=` operation also requires one shift and one inversion to create the mask: `&= ~(1U<<NumberOfBits)` or `&= ((~0U) << NumberOfBits)`, so that's a total of three instructions. (Compiler optimizations and instruction set differences will mean that this doesn't always translate into a 33% time difference)

Comment: @David: the question is not whether it is UB or not, that is pretty obvious. The question is why do compilers not obey the standard when they make the code behave in a sane way?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: When the program exhibits UB, _there simply is no standard to obey_ for the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Reinterpreting as an `int` violates aliasing rules. Reinterpreting as a `unsigned char[4]` doesn't. Do you need to support `NumberOfBits` values >=8 ? If not, you can just do the bitshift on `ptr[3]`

Comment: Why exactly does reinterpreting as `unsigned char[4]` not violate strict aliasing?

Comment: @sharptooth Because the standard explicitly allows it.

Comment: While this works, it is slightly slower than the union-hack version, so I think I'll go with that one. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: @sharptooth: and ultimately, because of C compatibility. `memcpy()` has to copy any POD type. (The actual rules are more permissive though, you can read the bytes of non-POD types too)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use floor() instead of converting to an int?

Comment: As mentioned above, floor is obscenely expensive computational wise. Using (int) instead of floor is a LOT faster.